# Printing multiple variables in a separate lines using a single print

Tags: python, printing

For example, I have two variables `int1 = 5` and `int2 = 3` How can I print both the integers in separate lines using only a single `print` without typecasting to `str`. (like the following in C++: `cout<<int1<<endl<<int2;`)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I think the duplicate target is a bit different. There are no answers there mentioning `sep='\n'`. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In python3:

```
print(string1, string2, sep='\n')
```

In python2:

```
print string1 + '\n' + string2
```

... or `from __future__ import print_function` and use python3's print

Since my first answer, OP has edited the question with a variable type change. Updating answer for the updated question:

If you have some integers, namely `int1` and `int2`:

Python 3:

```
print(int1, int2, sep='\n')
```

Python 2:

```
print str(int1) + '\n' + str(int2)
```

or

```
from __future__ import print_function

print(int1, int2, sep='\n')
```

or

```
print '\n'.join([str(i) for i in [int1, int2]])
```

Comment: or for python2: print("\n".join([string1, string2, string_n])
For not have to concatenate X "\n"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new line escape character and concatenate it between the two strings.

```
print string1 + "\n" + string2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print(string1 + "\n" + string2)
```

However, if one of the variables is an integer, you must convert is to a string first. If so:

```
str(string1)
```