# Use a line break to print out variables in the same print statement

Tags: python

I want this same print statement to give me these variables in separate statements:

```
x = 22.4
y = 23.4

print(y,\n x)
```

but Python doesn't seem to think it's obvious.

I have tried the `r/n` and I have also tried printing out my variables with separate print statements, but that is not what I want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing multiple variables in a separate lines using a single print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656381/printing-multiple-variables-in-a-separate-lines-using-a-single-print)

Comment: `for value in [x, y]: print(value)`

Comment: Yes!they all do,

Comment: am so happy now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
print(f'{y} \n{x}')
```

This will go good

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/

This link will explain how we use f- strings

Comment: thank you, it worked.

Comment: Yes sure. The f stands for the format I will share a good link where this will be explained

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/

Comment: Here you will find many f strings including the one I used

Comment: Here you will find many f strings including the one I used

Comment: @Tomerikoo thank you for reminding

Comment: Ohkay basically the `f'{variable} some lines etc etc'`

Comment: shift + enter for new line

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python

maybe this could help

Comment: @ErickKieti You can get ranked up ( having a better reputation ) by answering / editing / asking(many views or upvotes)    question

Comment: I dont think that chating in comments is a good option, do you have any other medium 
If not then it is fine

Comment: yeah that is a good website
shift + enter for newlines

Comment: Just for add - on If you have got a complete answer then you can also accept my answer by clicking on a button on left of answer

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you use:

```
print("{}\n{}".format(x,y))
```

Comment: most tutors recommend `print(f'{y} \n{x}')` , this is because your particular method is outdated and verbose for long tasks.thanks

Comment: Ok! However you prefer.